# Boundary conditions for diffusion equation with dirac-delta

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I have the following PDE:

$$\frac{\partial H(\lambda,r)}{\partial \lambda} - D \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r^2 \frac{\partial H(\lambda,r)}{\partial r}) = \delta(\lambda) \delta(\vec{r})
    \label{eq:H},\quad \lambda \geq 0$$

The text I am reading suggests solving this equation with zero right-hand side and the boundary condition:

$$H(\lambda,r)\bigg|_{\lambda=0} = \delta(\vec{r})$$

I don't understand how exactly this boundary condition is derived and why the resulting problem is equivalent to the original PDE. I come from a physics perspective so I don't have much knowledge on the correct formal treatment of distributions.

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic It is from this paper: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1697/1/012009 on page 3

Answer (score 0):

From physics perspective, at first, it is obvious, that right hand part is non-zero only at point (0,0), so physically it looks like boundary condition

And if you integrate equation through \lambda near zero, you get something like
H(0+,r) - H(0-,r) = \delta(r)
And we consider, that for negative \lambda H is equal to zero.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. As an advice, you could use Mathjax to write mathematics https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference